# Externalize web.xml params in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring

I have few parameters in web.xml file to be externalized. Application is in spring 4.0. Is there a spring way to do this?

More precisely, if I define PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in context file, is there a way to use that for fetching properties in web.xml?

This is what I tried:

In applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property
            name="location"
            value="classpath:/test.properties" />
        <property
            name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders"
            value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Then in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

But the below code returns param value as ${app.url}

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>appUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>${app.url}</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Comment: Guys, don't understand the negative votes!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as web.xml will be loaded before context initialization. The only solution for this is to move these properties to application server specific properties files.

I am using Tomcat and I moved this property to catalina.properties. Now it's working.